# How to create a frontend form and save the fields data into database in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can I create a frontend form and save that data in a database in Magento 2?

Comment: Do you want to create form on frontend side?

Comment: Yes, both UI & Server side.. If I save data, it should also save in DB

Answer (score 11):

Assuming we are creating new module `Company/Module`.

## Defining the module

> /app/code/Company/Module/**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Company_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
```

## Module registration

> /app/code/Company/Module/**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Company_Module',
__DIR__
);
```

## Create the frontend router

> /app/code/Company/Module/**etc/frontend/routes.xml**

Create a route for manage :

- GET request wich going to display HTML form template
- POST request wich going to send form data to Action Controller Class.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="companymodule" frontName="companymodule">
            <module name="Company_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

## Create the layout

> /app/code/Company/Module/**view/frontend/layout/module_index_booking.xml**

Create a basic layout for associate the Block to the form page phtml template

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>HTML title - The booking form page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\Booking" name="companymodule.booking" template="Company_Module::booking.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

## Create the Block

> /app/code/Company/Module/**Block/Booking.php**

Create a block with many functions you want for your form.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Block;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
            // companymodule is given in routes.xml
            // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
            // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder
        return $this->getUrl('companymodule/controller_name/action', ['_secure' => true]);
        // here controller_name is index, action is booking
    }
}
```

## Create the template

> /app/code/Company/Module/**view/frontend/templates/booking.phtml**

Create a template with your HTML form and add the form action corresponding to the routing.

```html
<h1>Booking page</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" type="text">
    <input name="lastname" type="text">
    <input name="phone" type="text">
    <input name="bookingTime" type="date">
    <input type="submit" value="Send booking informations">
</form>
```

## Create the Action Controller

> /app/code/Company/Module/**Controller/Index/Booking.php**

Create an Action Controller for manage the requests on the route.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Booking action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get booking data
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data
            $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
            $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
            $phone       = $post['phone'];
            $bookingTime = $post['bookingTime'];

            // Doing-something with...

            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Booking done !');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/companymodule/index/booking');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

In resuming you will must have the following architecture :

```
app
  ├ code
  |   ├ Company
  |   |   ├ Module
  |   |   |   ├ Block
  |   |   |   |   ├ Booking.php
  |   |   |   ├ Controller
  |   |   |   |   ├ Index
  |   |   |   |   |   ├ Booking.php
  |   |   |   ├ etc
  |   |   |   |   ├ frontend
  |   |   |   |   |   ├ routes.xml
  |   |   |   ├ view
  |   |   |   |   ├ frontend
  |   |   |   |   |   ├ layout
  |   |   |   |   |   |   ├ module_index_booking.xml
  |   |   |   |   |   ├ templates
  |   |   |   |   |   |   ├ booking.phtml
```

Then run following commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then you can access to your custom form page : http://localhost/companymodule/index/booking

*Happy coding!*

Comment: In which table it is saving the data ?

Comment: It is just an overall example of creating module. I have not saved data in any table neither I have created any table in this above module code. @samairali

Comment: ok . :) can you tell me specifically how can i add data to specific table ? i am trying to learn it but not getting enough resources .

Comment: This could really help you. Please refer,

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html

Comment: downvoted, because you answered it partially

Comment: I also specifically need to know how to send the form data into a database table (I have already created the table) but as per usual magento, there is a serious lack of information about how to do this properly... fun fun fun. Anyone with a tutorial or link to some useful documentation, that would be a lifesaver :(I really have looked!!!):

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the steps Below reference link on how to create modules in magento2.

All guidelines are this ->  [click here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/)